# Does there exist a norm on continuous real-valued function space?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, linear-algebra

I know the space of continuous real-valued function on closed set can be given a norm by integral. How about the continuous funcion on the real line? It may be non-integrable, like f(x)=x^2. So, does there exist a norm on it, and how to construct it?

Comment: While the question is perhaps a bit naive, I think it is natural enough, and the solution (if one is not using AC) is not obvious. I think @NateEldredge's comment would do fine as an answer

Comment: See also here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/62778/does-every-mathbbr-mathbbc-vector-space-have-a-norm

Answer (score 10):

Assuming the axiom of choice, yes, it has many norms.  Use Zorn's lemma to choose a Hamel basis $B \subset C(\mathbb{R})$.  I claim $|B| = \mathfrak{c}$, i.e. $C(\mathbb{R})$ has Hamel dimension $\mathfrak{c}$.  Since evaluating at rationals gives an injection of $C(\mathbb{R})$ into $\mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{Q}}$, we have $|B| \le |C(\mathbb{R})| = |\mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{Q}}| = \mathfrak{c}$.  On the other hand, $C_0(\mathbb{R})$ (the functions vanishing at infinity) is a separable Banach space, [hence has Hamel dimension $\mathfrak{c}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/141543/822), and it embeds linearly into $C(\mathbb{R})$.

So if you pick any normed space $(X, \|\cdot\|_X)$ of Hamel dimension at least $\mathfrak{c}$, you can find an injection from $B$ to a Hamel basis of $X$, and extend this to a linear injection $T : C(\mathbb{R}) \to X$.  Now it's easy to verify that the pullback $\|f\|_T := \|Tf\|_X$ defines a norm on $C(\mathbb{R})$.

If you choose $X$ to have Hamel dimension exactly $\mathfrak{c}$, you can choose $T$ to be a linear isomorphism, and in that case the normed space $(C(\mathbb{R}), \|\cdot\|_T)$ is isometrically isomorphic to $(X, \|\cdot\|_X)$.  For instance, you could choose $X$ to be any separable Banach space,  in which case your norm $\|\cdot\|_T$ will be complete.  You could even choose $X = \ell^2$ and find a norm which makes $C(\mathbb{R})$ a separable Hilbert space.

This is of course rather non-constructive.  You might ask if there is an "explicit" norm for which we can write down a formula, or whose existence can be shown without the axiom of choice.  The answer to that is no.  As I showed in [this Math.SE answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1018905/822), it is consistent with ZF plus the axiom of dependent choice (DC, a weakened version of the axiom of choice which is still sufficient for most of real analysis) that there does not exist any norm on the vector space $C(\mathbb{R})$.

The proof shows in ZF+DC that such a norm would let you construct a subset of a Polish space ($C(\mathbb{R})$ with the topology of local uniform convergence) which does not have the property of Baire, and then invokes the Solovay / Shelah result that it is consistent with ZF+DC that every subset of a Polish space has the property of Baire.